How Should I Build and Deploy Contact Us Page Angular on cPanel Hosting
I'm currently developing an app and have completed the front-end design. I have a section called "Contact Us Form" where I can store data and perform CRUD operations on my localhost. However, I need guidance on how to deploy this app on cPanel with the back-end integrated.
Could you provide some advice or techniques for this process?
Thank you!
I can storage data on MS-SQL, and perform CRUD operations on .NET Core.
But I'm opened to other techniques like NodeJS, MongoDB...
